# Kan extenstion and left adjoint

Tags: category-theory, proof-explanation

This is a continuation of the question asked here: [Kan extension "commutes" with a certain left adjoint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3774842/kan-extension-commutes-with-a-certain-left-adjoint).

Let $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$ be small categories and $\mathcal{C},\mathcal{D}$ an arbitrary category. Consider functors $F:\mathcal{A}\rightarrow\mathcal{B}$, $G:\mathcal{A}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}$, $K:\mathcal{B}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}$, $R:\mathcal{D}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}$ and $L:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow\mathcal{D}$, where $L$ is left adjoint to $R$ and $K=\text{Lan}_F(G)$. We want to show that
$$L\circ\text{Lan}_F(G)=\text{Lan}_F(L\circ G).$$

I have already convinced myself that for every functor $H:\mathcal{B}\rightarrow\mathcal{D}$, we get the following bijections:
$$ \begin{align} \text{Nat}\left(L\circ\text{Lan}_F(G),H\right) &
\cong \text{Nat}\left(\text{Lan}_F(G),R\circ H\right) \\ & \cong
\text{Nat}\left(G,R\circ H\circ F\right) \\ & \cong
 \text{Nat}\left(L\circ G,H\circ F\right)\\ & \cong
 \text{Nat}\left(\text{Lan}_F(L\circ G),H\right) .\end{align}$$

At this point, Borceux says the following:

> So $L\circ\text{Lan}_F(G)\cong\text{Lan}_F(L\circ G)$, by putting
> successively $H=L\circ\text{Lan}_F(G)$ and $H=\text{Lan}_F(L\circ G)$.

Following this procedure, I get
$$\text{Nat}\left(L\circ\text{Lan}_F(G),L\circ\text{Lan}_F(G)\right)\cong\text{Nat}\left(\text{Lan}_F(L\circ G),L\circ\text{Lan}_F(G)\right)$$
and
$$\text{Nat}\left(L\circ\text{Lan}_F(G),\text{Lan}_F(L\circ G)\right)\cong\text{Nat}\left(\text{Lan}_F(L\circ G),\text{Lan}_F(L\circ G)\right).$$

How do I use this to conclude $L\circ\text{Lan}_F(G)\cong\text{Lan}_F(L\circ G)$?–Anyway, mustn't I show this as an equality instead of an isomorphism?

**Edit:**

I have managed to prove the claim directly using the functor $L\circ\text{Lan}_F(G):\mathcal{B}\rightarrow\mathcal{D}$ and the natural transformation $L*\alpha:L\circ G\Rightarrow L\circ\text{Lan}_F(G)\circ F$, where $\alpha: G\Rightarrow\text{Lan}_F(G)\circ F$ is canonical natural transformation. I am still not clear about Borceux's reasoning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get an equality anyways because $\mathrm{Lan}$ is only defined up to isomorphism, so the best you can hope for is a canonical isomorphism - which is indeed what you get.

Borceux's reasoning is just reproving the Yoneda lemma, I don't understand why he says that again (or maybe he didn't prove Yoneda yet ? That would be awfully weird)

But essentially the point is that if you have a natural isomorphism $\hom(A,-)\cong \hom(B,-)$, then you get an isomorphism $B\cong A$ which is given by the image of $id_A\in \hom(A,A)\to \hom(B,A)$. That's why you "plug in $A$" (and to find its inverse you plug in $B$ and take the unique antecedent of $id_B$) : this is essentially a special case of the Yoneda lemma

Comment: Thank you for your help. The trouble is that $\mathcal{D}$ is not assumed to be cocomplete; in that case, how can one deduce the existence of $\text{Lan}_F(L\circ G)$? I thought the strategy here would be showing that $L\circ\text{Lan}_F(G)$ fulfills the properties of $\text{Lan}_F(L\circ G)$, no?

Comment: Well in this case you assume the existence of $\mathrm{Lan}_F(G)$ and prove (via these isomorphisms and the definition) that $L\circ \mathrm{Lan}_F(G)$ is a Kan extension of $L\circ G$ along $F$. But this doesn't seem to be the question you asked about

Comment: I know–but this would show that $\text{Lan}_F(L\circ G)$ is equal to $L\circ\text{Lan}_F(G)$, right? I mean this gives us equality instead of isomorphism. Whatever fits the properties of definition of the kan extension of $L\circ G$ along $F$ is called $\text{Lan}_F(L\circ G)$ (hence equal to $\text{Lan}_F(L\circ G)$), correct?

Comment: Well yes and no -  it depends on what you mean by equality

Comment: Sorry to bother you again: I have a quick question. Is the isomorphism $\text{Nat}\left(L\circ\text{Lan}_F(G),H\right)\cong\text{Nat}\left(\text{Lan}_F(L\circ G),H\right)$ natural in $H$?

Comment: Well in the string of isomorphisms you gave, all were natural, and a composite of natural isomorphisms is natural, so yes. That's how you can apply the Yoneda lemma

Comment: The existence should involve left adjoints preserving colimits, so, once $\mathcal{C}$ is cocomplete, we should have the necessary colimits in $\mathcal{D}$?